# Remove NSString from memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation

I have to remove an `NSString` (containing some confidential data) from memory but not only by setting it to `nil`, but by nullifying it's bytes. What I've tried so far is:

```
NSString *str = @"test";
NSLog(@"original string:%@", str);
CFStringRef ref = (__bridge CFStringRef)str;
const char * strPtr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(ref, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
memset(strPtr, 0, [str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"cleared string:%@", str);
```

but the function `CFStringGetCStringPtr` is returning `NULL` so it crashes at the line with the `memset`. Apple says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCStringPtr) that in some cases it is normal for that function to return `NULL`, but then I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just change the contents of the string before releasing the pointer?

Comment: It is immutable, so all I could do is to change the `str` to point to a different object, but then I could just simply set it to `nil` which is not enough

Comment: Such attempts to hide sensitive data is futile. Even when you manage to clear the memory, an attacker can obtain it before your memory is cleared. IMO, there is currently no way to prevent getting information from memory, or exploit other tricks to get confidential information, assuming the device is jail-broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store confident data as strings. You can't remove them from memory easily.

If possible, use `NSMutableData` to store confident data, instead.

Comment: What if it is a pin entered by the user? Should I convert it into NSData and keep it that way in the memory?

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do it this way then

Comment: An array of characters is also possible, just don't use strings. They are dangerous and they can be easily found in memory.

Comment: This is the most realistic approach.  You can't do anything about Apple's UI elements containing password text, except hope that when they're configured as such they will be responsible enough to destroy the input buffer.  Aside from that the only thing we can do is to store the data in a more controllable structure.  Less convenient but possible to encapsulate.

Comment: then how to remove NSMutableData from memory?

Comment: @SatishMavani Rewrite it with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"test"];

    NSLog(@"original string:%@", str);

    CFStringRef ref = ( CFStringRef)str;

    CFIndex stringLength = CFStringGetLength(ref), usedBytes = 0L;

    const char * strPtr = NULL;

    strPtr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(ref, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    char *freeUTF8StringPtr = NULL;

    for(CFIndex idx = 0L; (strPtr != NULL) && (strPtr[idx] != 0); idx++) 
    {
        if(strPtr[idx] >= 128) { strPtr = NULL; }
    }

    if((strPtr == NULL) && ((freeUTF8StringPtr = malloc(stringLength + 1L)) != NULL)) 
   {

    CFStringGetBytes(ref, CFRangeMake(0L, stringLength), kCFStringEncodingUTF8, '?', false, (UInt8*)freeUTF8StringPtr, stringLength, &usedBytes);
        freeUTF8StringPtr[usedBytes] = 0;
        strPtr = (const char *)freeUTF8StringPtr;

    }

    NSUInteger memorySize=[str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"cleared string:%@", str);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my string is immutable. With mutable strings the code I wrote doesn't crash. So I guess that was the main problem

Answer (score -1):

I have tried something like this below:-

```
NSMutableString *str = @"test";
NSLog(@"original string:%@", str);
CFStringRef ref = (__bridge CFStringRef)str;//kCFStringEncodingUTF16
const char * strPtr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(ref, kCFStringEncodingUTF16);
NSUInteger memorySize=[str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"cleared string:%d", memorySize);


Output :=  4
```

Comment: Ok, why would this help me? You are doing nothing with the original string.

Comment: This code is only not crashing, apart from this do you want to achieve ??

Comment: I know this is not crashing. Read the question again. It is crashing at the line with the `memset`which doesn't appear in your code.

Comment: Provides no valid answer.